# Grant access to SSRS report by SQL code

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have to grant access to 2 reports on SSRS for 40 colleagues. 
I have started to proceed this on report manager (ReportName -> security -> New Role Assignment -> paste the username -> select Browser role -> click OK)
But to repeat this 80 times is a bit boring.
I think SSRS executes a stored procedure in the background, because I found these records in ReportServer database.

Do you have any idea how to make this faster? By Executing a t-code or something?

Note: I cannot create AD Group to put these Users into and grant access for the Group.

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this easily. The tables, Users; Roles; Policies; PolicyUserRole look straight forward but I think you also need to populate SecData which might be a problem. You could half the time by putting the reports in the same folder, or creating a link to both in the a new folder, and then assigning permission to the folder rather than the individual reports.

Comment: Yes, finally I have put them into 1 folder and granted permission to that folder. But Unfortunately this is not the first time I have to grant access to reports for more than 10 user :(